# How to avoid null values in jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a field in my jasper report which has a expression value like

```
$F{address_street1}+" "+$F{address_street2}+ " " +$F{address_state} + " "+$F{address_country}+ " "+$F{address_zip}
```

My problem is that if any of the fields in here is null I get the null value between other things like

```
101 Main St****null****ILUnited States12345
```

Notice the highlighted null. Is there any way I can avoid that?

I have tried checking the null value for a particular field in it using boolean expression and replacing it with blank, but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 46):

Set the property `isBlankWhenNull` to true.

- In iReport check the Blank When Null checkbox when your field is selected.
- In jasper jrxml file: `<textField isBlankWhenNull="true">`

Comment: it does not work because my total field(which is a concatenation of more than one individual field) is not null only a part of field which is null, which I want to avoid

Comment: This answer covers a very common question... but it does not cover the question asked here. Although there is not enough information in the question to be sure, it would probably be sufficient to change the report language from "Groovy" to "Java".

Comment: NOT CORRECT for the specific question! read the answar below https://stackoverflow.com/a/3186360/1241276

Comment: this is not an answer for which the question asked. I dont understand how people upvoted this answer that much.

Answer (score 44):

In The Expression You are allowed to use the Java code.

So what You need to do is to check that the value of field is null if is then replace it with empty string.

```
$F{address_street1} == null ? "" : $F{address_street1}+ " " +
$F{address_street2} == null ? "" : $F{address_street2}+ " " +
$F{address_state} == null ? "" : $F{address_state}  + " " +
$F{address_country} == null ? "" : $F{address_country}+ " " +
$F{address_zip} == null ? "" : $F{address_zip}
```

Comment: Heads up to anyone still in IReport 3.7.4, this does not work. For some reason ($F{field} == null ? x : y) returns null (which gets translated to false in the java ternary operator).

Answer (score 13):

@Vash, Yes that is what I would do except I think you might want to put each expression inside of parentheses so that each expression is independent of the others. Like this:

```
($F{address_street1} == null ? "" : $F{address_street1}+ " ") +
($F{address_street2} == null ? "" : $F{address_street2}+ " ") +
($F{address_state} == null ? "" : $F{address_state}  + " ") +
($F{address_country} == null ? "" : $F{address_country}+ " ") +
($F{address_zip} == null ? "" : $F{address_zip})
```

Comment: I've been doing this for a long time but I hope someone has a less verbose solution.

Comment: better for me too: without parantheses i have jrxml compilation problems

Answer (score 10):

if you can use **jasperreports-functions** and you want to output String value, you can do it with function **T()** which returns text String or empty String.

> T($F{firstName})

Answer (score 7):

To solve this problem  first, check field properties Blank when null checkbox in IReport or if it is Jasper jrxml file: `<textField isBlankWhenNull="true">` .

Then I found **two ways** to solve this. Choose one way describes in  below.
1. Use expression syntax like this

`$F{variableName}.equals( "0" )? "" : $F{variableName}`

and you can use code like

```
$F{address_street1}.equals("0")? "" : $F{address_street1} + " " +  
$F{address_street2}.equals("0")? "" : $F{address_street2} + " " +
$F{address_state}.equals("0")? "" : $F{address_state} + " " +  
$F{address_country}.equals("0")? "" : $F{address_country} + " " +
$F{address_zip}.equals("0")? "" : $F{address_zip}
```

2. Use expression syntax like

`$F{variableName}== null ? "" : $F{variableName}`

and you can use code like

```
$F{address_street1} == null ? "" : $F{address_street1} + " " +  
$F{address_street2} == null ? "" : $F{address_street2} + " " +
$F{address_state} == null ? "" : $F{address_state} + " " +  
$F{address_country} == null ? "" : $F{address_country} + " " +
$F{address_zip} == null ? "" : $F{address_zip}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
($F{address_street1}.equals(null) ? "" : $F{address_street1}+ " ") + 
($F{address_street2}.equals(null)l ? "" : $F{address_street2}+ " ") +
($F{address_state}.equals(null) ? "" : $F{address_state}  + " ") +            
($F{address_country}.equals(null) ? "" : $F{address_country}+ " ") +           
($F{address_zip} .equals(null) ? "" : $F{address_zip})
```

Answer (score 3):

Try following:

```
$F{address_street1}.toString() == null ? "" : $F{address_street1}+ " " +
$F{address_street2}.toString() == null ? "" : $F{address_street2}+ " " +
$F{address_state}.toString() == null ? "" : $F{address_state}  + " " +
$F{address_country}.toString() == null ? "" : $F{address_country}+ " " +
$F{address_zip}.toString() == null ? "" : $F{address_zip}
```

Or
Set reports property:
   When resource missing type : Type Empty

both works in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I have the option (Blank when Null) checked for every field in the report and still seeing nulls on the fields. So, I used report expressions.

Since every report variable is a string, to check for null use:

```
$F{address_stree2}.equals("null")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are working in ecliple+jasper softReports you just fallow below steps
1.select field + *rightclick* and select ***showProperties*** option
2.click TextField select **BlankWhenNull**
3.Compile and Rebuild check it.

Answer (score 1):

i have similar case that i want to avoid showing **null** in the output if i have null parameter

i use `T($P{city})` in Expression editor, it evaluate to **empty** string if you did not pass parameter to it

> **T()** return the text string if the value is a string, otherwise an empty
>   string is returned

**example usage:**

```
$P{name} + " " + (T($P{city}).isEmpty() ? "" : " from " )+ (T($P{city}).isEmpty() ? "" : "\"" +  T($P{city}) + "\"")
```

if i pass parameter to $P{city} 
the result is :

> abdulkahliq from "Riyadh"

if i don't pass parameter to $P{city} the result is :

> abdulkahliq

Thanks and Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new **Style** 
mark it as `Default Style` 
go to: *Advanced > Blank When Null >* **true** 
That's it!

All TextField's will 'inherit' this setting 
(unless they 'touched' this property. `right-click` > `Reset To Default`)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a java Code

```
 package com.xyz

 Class ReportUtil 
  {
      public static String getMyString (String str1 , String str2)
         {
             if((str1!=null) && (str2!=null))
                 return str1 + " " + str2 ;
             else if str1==null
                  return str2 ; 
             return str1 ;                            
          }

   }
```

In JRXML , you can use the following expression in the textbox

```
com.xyx.ReportUtil.getMyString ($F{firstName},$F{lastName})
```

Set "Is blank When null" property to true

Regards,

Ankush

Answer (score 0):

if 
your fields are Strings just tick the property on (BLANK WHEN NULL). 
Otherwise use the ternary operator

> if null print something else print the field.

```
field==null?whatever:field 
field=null?false:true
```

These both ought to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the textfield height as 1, 
set the Stretch with overflow flag as true and Blank when null as true so when field value is blank it will not leave blank space between.

Answer (score -1):

```
($F{address_street1} + " " + $F{address_street2} + " " + $F{address_state} + " " +
    $F{address_country} + " " + $F{address_zip}).replaceAll("null", "")
```

Comment: Please format this better and give some explanation of why this is the answer.