# How to avoid error parsing empty text field for getting Date in Jasperreports

Tags: java, date, jasper-reports, timestamp

When I parse text field to get Date it's OK.
But if this text field is null because no data in the database, I am getting an exception.
How to get it work even if field is empty?

I use:
Jasperreports 5.6 via API, so I get my exceptions not in iReport, but while executing my java code;
Initial source of text field is oracle.Timestamp

Like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177323/how-to-avoid-null-values-in-jasper-reports) I tried to insert following:

```
$F{INCLUDE_TIME} == null ? "" : new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm").format(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd.HH.mm. ss.").parse($F{INCLUDE_TIME}))
```

But this works if I generate my report with iReport, and fails when I do it via API from Java code, using jasperreports engine.

The field is:

```
<field name="INCLUDE_TIME" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

My exception is:

> 18:19:53,564 ERROR Got exception while in generateReport:
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error
>   evaluating expression :   Source text : new
>   java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm").format(new
>   java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd.HH.mm.
>   ss.").parse(""+$F{INCLUDE_TIME}))

Comment: Ι delete my post because I din't known you are use  *.jrxml template.
But you can see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177323/how-to-avoid-null-values-in-jasper-reports

Maybe help you. Sorry but I don't know more details abouth this.
I hope to help someone who knows

Comment: Thank you, but this works just fine if I use iReport to generate the report. If I use it via jasperreports API, it fails as mentioned above.

Comment: if you want post your answer. Maybe help other memebers!

Comment: I edited my post above to make the question more consistent. Anyway, thank you for this hint, it could be useful as well

Comment: Are you try like this?
$F{INCLUDE_TIME} == null || $F{INCLUDE_TIME}.isEmpty() ? "" : new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm").format(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd.HH.mm. ss.").parse($F{INCLUDE_TIME}))

Comment: @sanBez Yes, I've just tried that, and got the same exception. The situation is the same: it works in iReport, but fails while using from Java code via API