# Multiple nested condition in jasper ireports

Tags: jasper-reports

I have multiple fields and i want to print all the ones which are not empty or not null in ireports.Can anyone please tell me how to do it.
I have around 20 fields and some of them would be non Empty, some would be empty and i want to print all non empty values on the reports.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid null values in jasper reports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177323/how-to-avoid-null-values-in-jasper-reports)

Answer (score 1):

In `iReport` select each field `$F{field}` which you do not want to print when null, and enter the following formula under "Print When Expression":

```
new Boolean($F{field} != null)
```

When your report renders, you should see nothing if the field happens to be null.